# Prepositions/Reference : In or From?

Tags: word-choice

I have a reference website with quotations from movies, tv-shows and anime.

Now the optimal way would be using a title like "Movie Quotes, TV Quotes and Anime Quotes" but since there's a character limit I need something shorter.

I thought of these:
*Quotes in Movies, TV and Anime* 
*Quotes from Movies, TV and Anime*

Now what I'm wondering is if there's any difference in terms of meaning between 'in' and 'from' in this context? Which one is better suited for my purpose?

---

From : —used as a function word to indicate the source

 In : used to indicate inclusion within space, a place, or limits

Comment: Why not just ***Movie, TV and Anime Quotes***?

Comment: Well the thing is that there are actually 5 subjects, not 3 (only mentioned 3 just to give a contextual example). Having a title like A, B, C, D and E Quotes makes it look like the site focuses on the subjects (A B C D E) rather than the quotes. That's why I try to place the keyword 'Quotes' first. Example: Cactus, Roses, Violets, Daffodils and Tulips Vases.

Comment: Depends on the nouns. If they're count nouns (like ‘movie(s)’, but unlike ‘TV’ and ‘anime’), the fact that they're in the singular should be enough to make it clear that they're the first part of a compound noun, even if there are some non-count nouns later on.

Comment: *from*, not *in*; unless the movies are themselves quoting from something else. Get the point?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Why **not** use a preposition as appropriate?

Comment: @Kris Ah! You're right, "Quotes in Movies", it might sound like the movies aren't the original source.
.JanusBahsJacquet Yes I understand what you mean. Grammatically it's clear, but when I put five seperate keywords before the targeted keyword it looks deceiving.

Comment: misleading* not deceiving

Answer (score 1):

Technically, "from" is the better option of the two. For the purposes of this forum, I should stop there, but "A, B, C, D, and E Quotes" is not effective usage for a title, and a string of five nouns standing in for adjectives is simply ponderous. If you want a subtitle, "Quotes from A, B, C, D, and E" works fine, but the title--the thing you want people to recognize, recall, and repeat--needs two things: brevity and pizazz. (Yes, everything from "but the title" onward belongs on a marketing forum instead.)

Comment: Can you add a quick explanation? Why is "from" better?

Comment: Good point, @MrHen! If the passages you are quoting were written by the author of the biography *Colonel Roosevelt*, say "quotations **from** *Colonel Roosevelt*. If the passages were found by the author in a prior source and are shown within quotation marks in that book, say "quotations **in** *Colonel Roosevelt*." A quotation is from its original source, and may later be found in a work that quotes the original.